# Javascript Syntax Error - I'm a complete noob and can't see it

Tags: javascript

I'm returning a **syntax error on line 9** (screenshot of IDE: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2578642/Error.png).

I'm complete noob and can't see the error, anyway, here's the code:

```
<input type = "image"  id = "myImage" src = "One.jpg" height ="130" width="173" border="0" Alt="Submit Form"  onclick="var fileref=document.createElement('script');fileref.setAttribute('type','text/javascript'); fileref.setAttribute('src', 'http://MYCONTENTLOCKER.com/guid?:1234567890'); showMessage(); setTimeout(changeImage, 30000)">
<br>
<span id = "message" style="display:none">You have completed this part!</span>

<script type = "text/javascript">

var count = 0;
function showMessage () {
if (count > 0) { // line 9
document.getElementById("message").style.display="block";
}
count ++;
}

function changeImage() {
document.getElementById("myImage").src = "Two.jpg"
}

</script>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you paste the code or prepare [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: When pasting code here, after doing so, highlight it and select the `{}` button on the toolbar.  Real code helps more than a screenshot of code.

Comment: Done! Thanks, didn't know you could do that :)

Comment: You are missing 2 semicolons (one in onclick other one in changeImage), but other than that your **screenshot** looks ok.

Comment: @Eugene semicolons aren't necessary. Though, IMHO are recommended...

Comment: Another note, do not sign your posts.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: @Xander Yes, I know, but it's a good code hygiene to use them.

Comment: There is no Error here. I think your Editor is showing error from cache.

Comment: Your code looks fine, though you should indent it to make it more readable.  I think your IDE is lying to you :-P

Comment: What IDE is that anyway? It looks ancient

Comment: Dreamweaver CS5 :) - MAC OS X so looks old? i don't know + All i want to do is put this into my wordpress blog so my content locker pops up and locks 'passwords' from appearing until they've completed a offer, arrh i don't know how it can be so hard :-p

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted is syntactically fine. I highly recommend you look into the script that you're "dynamically" loading through your `inline onclick` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript code looks fine, and the only thing I see that could be causing an issue is the space before and after the `=` in the HTML attributes.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
```

Should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

So, your code should look like this (I also suggest indenting your code.  Makes it easier to read):

```
<input type="image"  id="myImage" src="One.jpg" height="130" width="173" border="0" Alt="Submit Form"  onclick="var fileref=document.createElement('script');fileref.setAttribute('type','text/javascript'); fileref.setAttribute('src', 'http://MYCONTENTLOCKER.com/guid?:1234567890'); showMessage(); setTimeout(changeImage, 30000)">
<br>
<span id="message" style="display:none">You have completed this part!</span>

<script type="text/javascript">

var count = 0;
function showMessage () {
   if (count > 0) {
      document.getElementById("message").style.display="block";
   }
   count++;
}

function changeImage() {
   document.getElementById("myImage").src = "Two.jpg"
}

</script>
```

I'm not sure if that's the problem, but that's all I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that was your whole code. Would you please declare a valid HTML file? The highlighted **this** should've been a dead giveaway.

Comment: How is his HTML not valid, and why would the IDE show an error 6 lines after?

Comment: Hi, Sorry - I'm not a coder, so didn't realise, all i want to do is put this into a Wordpress site, have i don't something completely wrong? thanks, Harry.

Comment: You and I think this is valid HTML page, but if you look at the image, then the IDE doesn't quite know what it is. So it's highlighted the **this** in the code as a keyword.  So you need to tell your IDE that you're working with HTML.  The comment below by GGG, adds the HTML/BODY tags and viola.. valid HTML for your IDE.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't make any difference, hmm its probably a problem with my IDE (dreamweaver cs5), Sorry, I didn't code this :/ I just want for this to work on my Wordpress Blog, locking/hiding the text 'you've completed this part'. Thanks for all the help by the way guys!

Answer (score -1):

Well, it seems to [work fine](http://jsbin.com/ixuwew/edit#html,live) for me.

That said, the only thing I can possibly imagine being wrong is the `>` on that line is somehow getting escaped as an HTML entity before the page is served. Have you checked that the output of "view source" is indeed the same exact code you wrote?

Technically `script` elements and other elements with non-CDATA content containing "special" characters should have the content enclosed in a CDATA section. If your HTML code gets run through an XML parser at some point, it will choke on characters like `<`,`>`, and `&`.

With the CDATA section in the script, and the markup written as proper XHTML, the code would look something like this:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<input type="image" id="myImage" src="One.jpg" height="130" width="173" border="0" Alt="Submit Form"  onclick="imageClick()" />
<br />
<span id="message" style="display:none">You have completed this part!</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

var count = 0;
function showMessage () {
   if (count++ > 0) {
      document.getElementById("message").style.display="block";
   }
}

function changeImage() {
   document.getElementById("myImage").src = "Two.jpg"
}

function imageClick() {
   var fileref = document.createElement('script');
   fileref.setAttribute('type','text/javascript'); 
   fileref.setAttribute('src', 'http://MYCONTENTLOCKER.com/guid?:1234567890');
   showMessage(); 
   setTimeout(changeImage, 30000);
}

/* ]]> */    
</script>
</body></html>
```

---

Update: OK, I just realized that you're getting the error in your IDE, not necessarily in the browser. I don't know if the IDE is complaining about the unescaped triangle bracket or not, but i suspect it might be. I don't know if it's smart enough to acknowledge the CDATA section though. I'm curious if this will appease it. What IDE is that, anyway?

Comment: DW CS5 , Sorry, i don't know what your talking about haha - I didn't code this :/ I just want for this to work on my Wordpress Blog, locking the text 'you've completed this part'. Thanks!

Comment: @Harry What you have will probably work, unless wordpress or one of its plugins is running your content through an XML parser at some point. If that's the case, you'll need to put the javascript code in a cdata section as shown. It might also appease the IDE.

Comment: Ive tried to put in the data part, however the whole button still doesn't work, nothing happens when its Clicked - Thanks for all of the help

Comment: Ive tried using solely the code that you pasted in the JSBin in a fresh post in my wordpress blog, and it still doesn't work :/ hmm - ill try again tomorrow, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Harry whenever you get back to it, try stripping off the top and bottom line in my example.

Comment: Tried it, same result :S - I think that i need to do is put the button into a <div> format, but i don't know how to do that :S - do you know how to? Thanks!